# Поиск с фильтрами как гугле. React

Tags: reactjs, url, google-search

Необходимо сделать поиск который в url добавляет запросы на основе которых меняется контент. И если скопировать url и отправить другому пользователю чтоб у него был тот же контент что и у того кто отправил url.

Пример:

```
https://www.google.ru/search?q=stackoverflow
```

Надо на React как то такое реализовать.

Comment: react который будет отвечать за выборку? у вас какой то статичный контент?

Comment: @ИльяПаймушкин реакт за много отвечать будет еще и редакс буду подтягивать для исчисления нового состояния, нет контент не статический а запрашивается с сервера.